# How to position scrollbar of a fixed div with overflow scroll

Tags: html, css

my questions is actually about positioning the scrollbar of a fixed element
I tried mocking by setting some `border-left: 50% bgColor;` etc... but it didn't help much cause I had t ogive my main fixed div a `border-radius` which is being included in my radius etc

To be more clear this is the design I'm trying to get
[image]

I can mock it by creating another element and setting it's scroll position the same as of my main box, but I would prefer a CSS solution

Comment: What were your attempts?

Comment: Have the design on the picture, with separated scrollbar

Comment: This is not a freelance exchange where people write code for you based on a picture for free. Have you tried to solve your problem yourself?

Comment: I know what stackoverflow is, this is a perfect question for this platform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Style the scrollbar with css and add a negative `margin`. The starting point:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: lightgray;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.filter {
  position: fixed;
  top: 12px;
  left: 12px;
  width: min(280px, calc(100% - 2 * 12px));
  height: min(320px, calc(100% - 2 * 12px));
  border-radius: 12px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.filter:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  inset: auto 0 0;
  height: 12px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #f2f2f2, transparent);
  pointer-events: none;
  border-radius: 0 0 12px 12px;
}

.filter-head {
  padding: 12px;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #999;
  flex: none;
}

.filter-head:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  inset: calc(100% + 1px) 0 auto;
  height: 12px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f2f2f2, transparent);
  pointer-events: none;
}

.filter-body {
  overflow-y: auto;
  min-height: 1px;
  margin-right: -20px;
  padding: 12px 24px 12px 12px;
}

.filter-body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 40px;
}
.filter-body::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  border-radius: 40px;
  border: solid 8px transparent;
  background-clip: padding-box;
}
.filter-body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #999;
  border-radius: 40px;
  border: solid 8px transparent;
  background-clip: padding-box;
}
```

```html
<section class="filter">
  <header class="filter-head">
    <h4>Filter</h4>
  </header>
  <div class="filter-body">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia, reprehenderit amet molestias iusto sequi velit architecto eveniet maxime distinctio non enim eaque beatae alias placeat aliquam recusandae autem voluptatem mollitia qui nemo. Vitae, unde, animi, repellat voluptates aut ex quae nam quisquam totam nulla autem sunt labore quas voluptatibus hic id odit fuga aliquam modi expedita fugit incidunt officia. Dicta, minus, impedit veniam doloremque quaerat accusantium laborum praesentium repellat. Quod quibusdam in corporis deleniti. Iusto, beatae recusandae animi dicta facere.
  </div>
</section>
```

---

*P.S.* [*Can I use*](https://caniuse.com/?search=-webkit-scrollbar)

Answer (score -2):

To position the scrollbar for a fixed `<div>` element with `overflow: scroll`, you can use CSS to specify the dimensions and set `position: fixed`.

Comment: Can you clarify your answer? I've tried everything but nothing worked